# How do I change the background color in rst2pdf?

Tags: rst2pdf

When I generate any file using `rst2pdf` command line, the background color for the generated PDF files is not white, but a kind of light green.

How do I set the background color to white/transparent? These files must be printed.

Additionally: how do I put filenames as headers?